# <?php echo vs <?= is one "echo" better than the other? (in normal PHP and in CakePHP)

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, echo

In a lot of CakePHP examples, I see `<?php echo $myVar; ?>`  I've always written this in shorthand like `<?php=$myVar?>`

Is there any difference?  Is `<?php echo` better for some reason?  I always lean toward the shorter, but - when I see everyone else using the `<?php echo`, I wonder - maybe I'm doing it wrong.

What about in CakePHP - is it different for some reason?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<?=` or `<?php=` has to be enabled for it to work properly via the [short_open_tag](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) in your php.ini.  Since some systems out there have this value disabled, it's encouraged that you use `<?php echo` to ensure that your code will always work on any system it runs on.

Comment: could not sum it up it up better my self, +1

Comment: @Matt It's certainly never anything I've turned on manually - on ANY server - and it's always worked just fine.  I appreciate your feedback, but saying that you "don't think" it's enabled by default, when all past experience tells me otherwise doesn't help answer the question.

Comment: Also, 'in cakePHP' wouldnt make any difference at all. Its just a framework, it wont impact anything language-related.

Comment: @TJH - agree - just wasn't sure why almost all normal PHP code examples I see use <?=, and all cake examples I see use <?php echo

Comment: If it's just a one-liner in the ini file, wouldn't it be better, if moving servers, just to change that one line instead of adding an extra 9 characters every time you want to echo something?  (just playing devil's advocate a bit, and to better understand this answer)

Comment: Well, if it's a personal project, you're certainly at your own discretion to do so.  This is generally done for people sharing code on the web, in public projects, etc.  Since others will see & use shared code, it helps to prevent others from running into the inevitable questions about why it's not working when it should.